# PHP templating is terribly slow

Tags: php, mysql, regex, system, templating

I've got my own simple templating system, which is based on regex. [Here it is](http://ideone.com/nFSElK)

It is designed in a way I can just pass array from mysql result and it will return html code from a defined template file.

So if I pass array

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(5) {["DATE"]=> string(11) "21.04. 2013" ["NICK"]=> string(7) "Nashren"} 
[1]=> array(5) {["DATE"]=> string(11) "22.10. 2013" ["NICK"]=> string(13) "Superman"} 
[2]=> array(5) {["DATE"]=> string(11) "10.07. 2013" ["NICK"]=> string(13) "Superman"}
```

and have template

```
<td class="forum-last"> <strong>{{DATE}}</strong> <br> {{NICK}} </td>
```

It will return as expected

```
<td class="forum-last"> <strong>21.04. 2013</strong> <br> Nashren </td>
<td class="forum-last"> <strong>22.10. 2013</strong> <br> Superman </td>
<td class="forum-last"> <strong>10.07. 2013</strong> <br> Superman </td>
```

BUT! In this particular example, it takes literaly YEARS to execute ( like 5 seconds or so ).

Sql query which I am trying to display is:

```
SELECT forum_kategorie.NAME,forum_kategorie.DESC,DATE,uzivatele.NICK,USR
FROM `zpravy`
LEFT JOIN forum_kategorie ON CONCAT( NAME,  "forum" ) = URL
LEFT JOIN uzivatele on USR = uzivatele.ID

WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE)
               FROM zpravy
               WHERE CONCAT( NAME,  "forum" ) = URL)
GROUP BY NAME
```

Here's the usage of the script above.

```
include("php/themizer.php"); 



    $theme = new Themizer("forum-item",$res);

    $list = array("data" => $theme->getResult());

    $final = new Themizer("forum-table",$list);

     echo $final->getResult();
```

Any tought what it could be?

Comment: *it takes literally YEARS to execute (like 5 seconds or so)*.. So not years then.

Comment: Is the template parsing taking a long time or the MySQL query?

Comment: Use existent template engine, or none...

Comment: You should check the meaning of "literally" - it means really. So does it take literally years, or just seconds?

Comment: RoyalBg and ever since, template engines extinct
ExplosionPills Now it looks like its Mysql query
Chris well...yeah

Answer (score 1):

The columns that you use in join should be indexed.

`forum_kategorie.name, zpravy.date, url`

Answer (score 0):

Did you measure the operations (mysql query and template handling) seperately?

Answer (score 0):

Using a RegEx (or SearchReplace) functions ARE really slow.
Every Request says the templates must parsed and the replacement's must done.

Constructs like that, have many disadvantage like not cacheable etc.

Take a look at [smarty.net](http://smarty.net) - this is a good php template engine.
Easy to use.

If you don't like to use Smarty, you can also use plain PHP. 
It is a template engine, too.

Simply put you HTML in to separated PHP files.
You can use short tags `<?=$var>` to out stuff.
Of curse you can also use long tag's.
Additionally you have all php functions available including loops.
Use subtemplates with the `include` command.

Try to avoid mixing program logic with display logic.

Comment: Actually I am now using separated PHP files, in my newer projects. This is just something older, where this is implemented. It has its reasons, html scripters can add templates on their own.
Thanks for advices

Comment: If you like answers use upvote, please. if one answer is the answer of your question use accept answer (this can only one) - thanks